# (LibGdx) No control over sound?

Tags: java, libgdx

I can't stop music when a key is pressed. I'm not sure why, but when I call .pause() .stop() and .dispose() nothing happens at all.

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
      Theme.pause;
      Theme.dispose;
      //This is what's not working, in the update() it constantly checks if "A " is pressed
        main.setScreen(main.otherScreen);   
    } //this if statement is called in my  update method. Every thing but stoping the music works
```

Comment: What type does `Theme` have? Assuming it is of type `Music`, should you not be calling `Theme.pause()` and `Theme.dispose()` (notice the function call)? Why not add a `Gdx.app.log("music", "a pressed - turning off");` to make sure that you are calling that code, and only calling it once?

Comment: @tucuxi Yes, it is music. It is being called because I did a system output as well as switch screens.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call this in update method, as every time the update is called it will try to pause your Theme music and will try to dispose it which will generate exception or unwanted behaviour.

Better way is to use this method which comes from EventListener interface or you can extend InputAdapter class. Stage extends InputAdapter class so you can override this using stage.

```
    @Override
    public void keyUp(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Keys.A) {
            //if it is looping
            Theme.setLooping(false);
            Theme.stop();
            Theme.dispose();
        }
    }
```